Issue accessing environment variables defined in .dev.vars with Cloudflare Workers, Hono, and Bun
I'm working on a project using Cloudflare Workers, Hono, and Bun. I have defined my secret variables in a .dev.vars file as recommended by the Cloudflare Workers documentation. Here's the content of my .dev.vars file:
APPWRITE_ENDPOINT=
APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID=
APPWRITE_API_KEY=

My goal is to use these environment variables to configure a client that I want to share across multiple routes in my index.ts file, without defining the client inside the route handlers.
Here’s a snippet of my index.ts code:
import { Hono } from "hono";

const app = new Hono();

const client = new Client()
  .setEndpoint("") // I want to use APPWRITE_ENDPOINT here
  .setProject("")  // And APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID here
  .setKey("");     // And APPWRITE_API_KEY here

app.get("/users", (c) => {
  const users = new Users(client);
  const list = users.list();
  return c.json(list);
});

export default app;

I want to initialize the client outside of the route handlers so I can reuse it across different routes. My issue is that I'm unsure how to access the environment variables defined in the .dev.vars file from my code. How can I properly load these environment variables into my index.ts file and use them to configure the client globally, rather than within each route?
Is there a specific method in Cloudflare Workers or Bun to retrieve these variables?
Thank you in advance for your help!

First load the environment variables using dotenv
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()


if it doesn't load correctly it's probably because of your file name so you might need to use .config({ path: [ "./.dev.vars" ] })

Then access them as follows
process.env.APPWRITE_ENDPOINT


Thanks man, I understand that CF Workers doesn't allow to do this outside of context.
